# Get every value after certain characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Say I have a `string = 'iwebeivb&euro;&nbsp;25.00\n uyrewgiwebeivb&euro;&nbsp;26.00\n uyrewg iwebeivb&euro;&nbsp;27.00\n uyrewg`
How could I get every value after every `&euro;&nbsp;`?

I can only figure out how to get the first one: (25.00)

Comment: how are you getting the first one? have you tried regex?

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> string = 'iwebeivb&euro;&nbsp;25.00\n uyrewgiwebeivb&euro;&nbsp;26.00\n uyrewg iwebe
    ivb&euro;&nbsp;27.00\n uyrewg'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('&euro;&nbsp;([\d.]+)', string)
['25.00', '26.00', '27.00']
```

The regular expression above will capture all the numbers (`[\d.]+`) that are preceded by `&euro;&nbsp;` and return a list with the matches. The `()` surrounding `[\d.]+` means that this is the matching group we want to extract.